# How do I print out on a piece of paper with a button click

Tags: image, delphi, printing, delphi-7

I'm searching for a solution on printing out a page using a button `OnClick` event.

Let me give you an example:

With a button `OnClick` event, the code will randomly place certain images next to each other. With every click, I want those pictures (either the same or a different button) printed out on a piece of paper.

I tried searching for any connection with Delphi and printer in toolbar, but had no luck.

Comment: Best done by using a reporting library, such as QuickReports.

Comment: @kometa123: If you wonder why your question is being downvoted, I think I can give you some insight. Asking "How do I print a page using Delphi?" could be a good question. An answer might guide you through the basics of printing. This code can be made to run (1) when you click a button, (2) when you chose a menu item, (3) at 03:00 each Sunday morning, (4) when you change the item in a combo box, (5) when the mouse leaves a progress bar, etc. As you see, the "button OnClick" part has nothing to do with the printing part. Your Q, however, seems to indicate that these parts are inseparable.

Answer (score 3):

In principle, it is very easy to print using Delphi. You basically draw on the page's canvas as you'd draw on an on-screen canvas using the VCL (that is, using the Windows GDI).

Here is a very simple example:

```
procedure PrintRects;
const
  Offset = 100;
  RectCountY = 8;
  RectCountX = 4;
var
  S: string;
  TitleRect: TRect;
  MainRect: TRect;
  j: Integer;
  i: Integer;
  RectWidth,
  RectHeight: Integer;
  R: TRect;

  function GetRectRect(X, Y: Integer): TRect;
  begin
    Result := Rect(
      MainRect.Left + X * RectWidth,
      MainRect.Top + Y * RectHeight,
      MainRect.Left + (X + 1) * RectWidth,
      MainRect.Top + (Y + 1) * RectHeight
    );
  end;

begin

  with TPrintDialog.Create(nil) do
    try
      if not Execute then
        Exit;
    finally
      Free;
    end;


  Printer.BeginDoc;
  try

    Printer.Canvas.Font.Size := 42;
    S := 'My Collection of Rects';

    TitleRect := Rect(
      Offset,
      Offset,
      Printer.PageWidth - Offset,
      Offset + 2 * Printer.Canvas.TextHeight(S)
    );

    MainRect := Rect(
      Offset,
      TitleRect.Bottom + Offset,
      Printer.PageWidth - Offset,
      Printer.PageHeight - Offset
    );

    RectWidth := MainRect.Width div RectCountX;
    RectHeight := MainRect.Height div RectCountY;

    Printer.Canvas.TextRect(TitleRect, S, [tfSingleLine, tfCenter, tfVerticalCenter]);

    for j := 0 to RectCountY - 1 do
      for i := 0 to RectCountX - 1 do
      begin
        R := GetRectRect(i, j);
        Printer.Canvas.Brush.Color := RGB(Random(255), Random(255), Random(255));
        Printer.Canvas.FillRect(R);
      end;

  finally
    Printer.EndDoc;
  end;

end;
```

This produces the following page:

[image: A screenshot of the Microsoft Windows XPS viewer displaying the printed page produced by the above Delphi code snippet.]

Needless to say, instead of solid-colour rectangles, you could print your images here in this grid.

Hence, if you know how to draw things on a form (using `TCanvas`, that is, Windows GDI), you can use the same methods to draw on a printed page.

And of course, you can call this procedure when you click a button:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PrintRects;
end;
```