# Delphi - How to add multiple JPG images to a TCanvas and print them

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

As a Delphi programmer I'm a bit of a hack - learned bits and pieces along the way, mostly self taught.

I'm working on a program for fun that's a database for an out of print card game.  Has info of the cards and links to a JPG of the card image.

Was talking to someone about it and they said "Wouldn't it be cool if you could render multiple card images on a page at 2.5 x 3.5 inches and print them".

Legal issues aside (I won't be distributing this without express permission from the former publisher), I wanted to see if it could be done as an exercise to teach me how to use TCanvas.  Unfortunately I've really got no idea how to do this.

I'm working with an 8.5 x 11 inch page, so I'd want a 2.3 x 3.5 card image which gives me about an inch to play with that's not taken up by card images, so like 0.25 inches page margins all around and .25 inches between each image.  This would put 9 cards on the page.

For what I have written in my program so far, I can drop a TImage on a form and read the associated jpg file for any given card from disk and show it on the form.

Assume I have built a deck of these cards and want to print the images of my "deck".   How do I then take that associated image for each card, resize it so that it would fit into a 2.5 x 3.5 space on a canvas and then continue loading images until I've got 9 on the page.  Then I'd want to move to a new page and do it again until I've printed the cards in my deck (usually around 50 of them - so about 6 pages).

I've been doing some searching and I'm not sure how to deal with these aspects

- Resize the JPG once read
- Position it on the canvas - and get 9 images total there

The current images are (for the most part) 390 x 546 pixels. (which is the correct ratio for 2.5 x 3.5 inches).

Also, in order to try to preserve ink & paper, is there a way to "preview" the canvas before you send it to the printer (a print preview if you will), or is it just a huge trial and error thing until you get it right.

While specific code example would be preferred, I'm willing to do some legwork if I could even get a pointer to a website that showed how to work with these objects.

About 15 years ago I mucked around with putting Text onto a TCanvas and printing it, but I'm not sure how to make this work with a JPG after reading from disk and then resizing it to print to the scale I want here.

Anyone able to offer some pointers for me here ?

Oh if it matters, I'm working with Delphi XE3 Enterprise / Windows 10.

Thanks.

Comment: Study the `StretchBlt` WinAPI call to draw the contents on one DC (canvas.handle) to another one to a determined position and sizes.

Comment: You might find some inspiration here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60366803/282848

Comment: Just draw the TPicture on the canvas, with proper position and scaling, with regular VCL commands. Not more difficult than writing text on a canvas. Please at least show some code of your attempt. Than switch your question into two: one about printing Jpeg, another about preview. A preview is simple: just draw on a TPaintBox canvas. Note that both has already been answered in SO or on the web, for sure. Did you at least Google for it?

Comment: While it is possible to render multiple images on a printer canvas I think that for what you need it would probably be much easier for you to just use one of the reporting components that ship with Delphi like Fast Report for instance to create a desired print report. Main advantages of such approach is that pretty much all report components support generating print preview with no additional code not to mention that some report component allows you to design your print report visually in similar way as you would be designing forms.

Comment: "in order to try to preserve ink & paper". I always print to a PDF or XPS printer when I want to preview a document in an app that doesn't support print preview. Mainly I use that to try my own printing routines. Most contemporary Windows PCs have such a virtual printer driver.

Comment: Thanks for the assorted comments.  Yes, had googled, hadn't find much that made much sense to me, so will play with a few of these comments and link as well and the code in the post below and see what I can come up with over the next few days.  Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some rude way to make it work.

First of all, I see at least two ways to make it:

- load all images into array or ObjectList (that is better I suppose) and then make transofrmations and draw them on canvas;
- load, transform and draw image one by one;

Which of them the better one? I don't know. I'd prefer second because it will take less RAM I suppose.

```
uses ...,jpeg, SysUtils, Graphics;

...

const CARD_WIDTH:integer = /*your card width*/;
const CARD_HEIGHT:integer = /*your card height*/;
const MARGIN_X:integer = 0; //you can change it if you want to
const MARGIN_Y:integer = 0; //you can change it if you want to
...

//Load images. You can call it from button's OnClick event;
function LoadImages(aWidth, aHeight:integer):TBitmap;
var i:integer;
    lImage:TJpegImage;
    lResizedBmp:TBitmap;
    lPosX,lPosY:integer; //it can be TPoint as well       
begin
result := TBitmap.Create;
lPosX := MARGIN_X;
lPosY := MARGIN_Y;
try
result.Width := aWidth;
result.Height := aHeight;
//I don't know how you will get filenames, so I'll make some dummy code
for i := 0 to 10 do
   begin
      lImage := TJpegImage.Create;
      lResizedBmp := nil;
      try
         lImage.LoadFromFile('C:\' + inttostr(i) + '.jpg'); //it's bad code just to demonstrate the way we load file. I don't remember if "i.toString()" is acceptable in XE3.
         lResizedBmp := ResizeJpeg(lImage, CARD_WIDTH, CARD_HEIGHT);
         result.Canvas.Draw(lPosX, lPosY, lResizedBmp);
         //let's calculate next card position
         lPosX := lPosX + CARD_WIDTH + MARGIN_X;
         if (lPosX + CARD_WIDTH + MARGIN_X > aWidth) then
            begin
            lPosX := MARGIN_X;
            lPosY := lPosY + MARGIN_Y + CARD_HEIGHT;
            end; 
      finally
         FreeAndNil(lImage); 
         if assigned(lResizedBmp) then
            FreeAndNil(lResizedBmp)
      end;
   end;
except 
  on (e:Exception) do
   begin
      FreeAndNil(result);
      raise e;
   end; 
end;
end;

//Resize image and convert it into Bitmap
function ResizeJpeg(aJpg:TJpegImage; aWidth, aHeight:integer):TBitmap;
var lProxyBmp:TBitmap;
begin
result := TBitmap.Create;
try
   result.Width := aWidth;
   result.Height := aHeight;

   lProxyBmp := TBitmap.Create;
   try
      lProxyBmp.Assign(aJpg);    
      result.Canvas.StretchDraw(result.Canvas.ClipRect, lProxyBmp);
   finally
      FreeAndNil(lProxyBmp);
   end;

except
   on e:Exception do
   begin
      FreeAndNil(result);
      raise e;
   end;
end;
end;
```

So, you have all procedures to make your page. Just make Form, place TImage and two buttons on in. Set TImage's `Stretched` and `Proportional` properties to `true`. Set buttons' `captions` to `Load` and `Print`. Don't forget to add unit with procedures to `uses` or make them as Form's methods. Add private field `_bmp:TBitmap` to your `Form`;

For `Load` button:

```
//Page preview. 
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender:TObject)
begin
if assigned(_bmp) then
   FreeAndnIl(_bmp);

_bmp := LoadImages(2000,3000);
Image1.Picture.Assign(_bmp);
end;
```

For `Print` button:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender:TObject)
begin
if not assigned(_bmp) then
begin
  ShowMessage('Click "Load" first');
  Exit;
end;

with TPrintDialog.Create(nil) do
try
if not Execute then
  Exit;
finally
  Free;
end;

Printer.BeginDoc;
try
   Printer.Canvas.Draw(0,0,_bmp);
finally
   Printer.EndDoc;
end;
end;
```

After I checked this code on Delphi 10.1 using PDF printer I got my pdf file.

I've tried to make it as simple as possible, but there is plenty of code. I could miss something, but I'm ready to help. All constants can be made as variables and passed as function's params, it's up to you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will play with this over the coming day or two and see what I can do with it.

Comment: I took this code and played with it a little, got it running and generated a PDF...  Marvelous. I have some questions about things I'm not quite understanding.

It seems to load the TImage with compressed versions of the individual images, then move the image to the Printer canvas and print it.  If I was trying to get say 50 cards printed, 9 per page (in a 3x3) would id be correct to do printer.begindoc / load the first 9 images / printer.NewPage / Load the next 9 until done, then Printer.EndDoc ?

Comment: I'm unsure what the LoadImages(2000,3000) is doing.  My image files are 390 pixels wide and 546 pixels high on disk.   I would want to print them 3 across and 3 down per page.  A standard 8.5 x 11 inch page is 215 x 279 mm.  1 mm is 3.7795275591 pixels (if my google-fu is correct).  That's about 815 pixels by 1054 pixels.  To keep scale, let's say I resize my images to 240 x 336 - if placed on the page with that size I'd get 3 across and 3 down.   I'm playing with it after posting this extra question to see if I can work it out but your guidance would be appreciated

Comment: I had tried size the TImage to be 815 x 1054 pixels, but when printing the output to a PDF, even though the Timage on the form is mostly filled, it's not filling the whole page.   It's late and it's time to go to bed but if you have pointers to get past what I'm missing here, I'd appreciate it

Comment: Yes, you can do it with `Printer.NewPage`.

Comment: `LoadImage` is loading image and fetching them to the page. 2000 and 3000 are width and height of the page measured in pixels. So, if you want to make page with 815x1054 pixels just call `LoadImage(815,1054)`. But I have to mention that TImage is just preview of your page - it's scaled and can be used as preview, not to change print area.

Comment: One last comment before I disappear for the night.   I set Width and Height to be 240 x 336 and changed LoadImages to call with 815 x 1054.   The TImage filled with a 3x3.  When I printed it to the PDF it's appearing as a quite tiny little bit in the top left, so I'm definitely missing something important here.   Thanks for any help

Comment: I suppose that Google is not totally correct and your printer has resolution other then ~3.7 pixels in mm. Try to increase width and height in `LoadImage` and check result.

Comment: Yep, increased the 2000,3000 to 3500, 4900 and the card size to 1000x1400 - getting closer, will play some more after I've had some sleep.  Getting closer.   Thanks again!  I'll have to see if I can work out how many pixels are on my page - that would take a lot of the guess work out of it.

Comment: Or you can search your printer's dpi in Google. I think it can be better solution.

Comment: Well, I have the prototype working well now for printing one page.  As soon as I can find some free time, I'll see if I can get multiple pages working correctly.   Seems like I'm working with a basis of 600 DPI and that made a 2.5 x 3.5 inch size fairly easy to calculate.   I'll update and accept the answer once I'm finished with my testing.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I have a successful thing working, throwing a new page after every 9 images.  Thank you, @mrNone